# Is there an easy way to parse a list of tuples generated by python's print, using Python?

Tags: python, list

Suppose I have a list of tuples generated by the following list comprehension:

```
foo = [(x**2, x*2) for x in xrange(10)]
```

If I then write

```
print foo
```

I get output that looks like:

```
[(0, 0), (1, 2), (4, 4), (9, 6), (16, 8), (25, 10), (36, 12), (49, 14), (64, 16), (81, 18)]
```

Suppose I had previously written this output to a file `foo.txt`, and wanted to read this output back into Python as a list of tuples again. Note that this is a toy example because I could obviously just rewrite the list comprehension, but in my real use case, I did some expensive computation to generate the original list of tuples, and I'd rather not repeat the computation.

Is there a way to do this without manually parsing using regex or some other standard string parsing method?

Comment: `ast.literal_eval` but next time consider saving your data with `pickle`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're looking for [`ast.literal_eval()`](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
import ast
with open('foo.txt', 'r') as myfile:
    fileoutput = myfile.read() # Assuming the whole file is just the list

original = ast.literal_eval(fileoutput)
for i in original:
    print i
```

Prints:

```
(0, 0)
(1, 2)
(4, 4)
(9, 6)
(16, 8)
(25, 10)
(36, 12)
(49, 14)
(64, 16)
(81, 18)
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use [pickle](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html).

To save to a file do:

```
with open('dump.txt','w') as f:
    pickle.dump(object,f)
```

and to load the object back do:

```
with open('dump.txt') as f:
    object = pickle.load(f)
```

Haidro's answer is good if you are only doing simple objects, but you should use pickle for more complex objects.

Comment: You should use `pickle` in all cases for saving python objects, OP was taking the wrong approach